# Photosynthesis - Light Intensity

Tags: photosynthesis, botany

Say I was conducting an experiment for photosynthesis. If I moved light closer to the plant, what effect would this have on the process of photosynthesis?

Comment: Could you list a few ways that you've tried to research this question before asking here so we know that you've put effort into the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rate of photosynthesis varies from plant to plant. Some plants require more light and some require less. If you move light closer to the plant, in most scenarios the rate of photosynthesis is likely to be increased. For some plants a minimal light is enough for their photosynthesis, so for those plants, moving light source closer or further will have less effect.

Comment: yes - Individual genetic composition often trumps the typical assumptions of physics in biology.